# Post your question/answer button moves down when clicked

Tags: bug, design

When you click (and hold) left click on the post question or post answer button (and possibly a few other buttons) the button will move down a few pixels. Which would be fine if it just looked like it moved down, however the clickable area of the button also moves.

So if you click at the top of these buttons it will not work as when you release the click the cursor is no longer on the button.

> [image]

Comment: Although rare, it seems like a legit bug, so +1 :)